# onclick class not firing on dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

this is the data im loading dinamically

```
$('<tr id="data[i].id" class="pedido_row">').html("
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].user_created + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].store_created + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].product_code + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].product_info + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].warehouse + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].cost_center + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].quantity + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].time_created + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\"><input class=\"dispatch_pedido\" id=\"0\" type=\"button\" value=\"Despachar Pedido\" /></td>
").appendTo('#pedidos');
```

then I added click event with this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', ".dispatch_pedido", function() {
        alert("hello world");        
    });
});
```

but its not working for dynamic created ids and not even for the ones that are loaded initially on the page.

function onclick works on data loaded with the page but not dynamic data so I'm trying to use  ON to get both to work but I haven't been able to do it.

Comment: what version of jquery are you using? & are you sure that jQuery is included in your DOM?

Comment: Is the javascript being added dynamically as well? or does that happen on page load? I think that you might just not have JQuery, try setting up the listener without using jquery and see if it works

Comment: ok.. then you can't use `on()`. It only works for version 1.7+. Use .live() instead `$(".dispatch_pedido").live(click, function() {`

Comment: @Krishna thanks Im using and older version so i needed to use live...  Ive been on this all day without noticing the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try changing you code to this.

```
$(".dispatch_pedido").live('click', function(){
    // your code
});
```

I know the live() method is deprecated but, when using dynamic created html elements then the events doesn't work.

Comment: live() is not available after Jquery 1.6

Comment: Im using jquery-1.4.2 so this was the solutions since is and old version it doesnt support on. my question is if I update jquery to newest version would it affect others functions that use live?

Comment: Well, I worked on a project using JQ 1.8.2 I think, and the live() method was already there. I tried on('click') for dynamic generated content without success. BTW mark this questions as the selected if it helped you ;)

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, problem is with table row creation script. **You need to create multi-line strings properly**

```
$('<tr id="data[i].id" class="pedido_row">').html("<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" 
      + data[i].user_created 
      + "</td><td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" 
      + data[i].store_created 
      + "</td><td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">"
      + data[i].product_code 
      + "</td><td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" 
      + data[i].product_info 
      + "</td><td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" 
      + data[i].warehouse 
      + "</td><td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" 
      + data[i].cost_center 
      + "</td><td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" 
      + data[i].quantity 
      + "</td><td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" 
      + data[i].time_created 
      + "</td><td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">"+
      "<input class=\"dispatch_pedido\" id=\"0\" type=\"button\" value=\"Despachar Pedido\" />"+
      "</td> ").appendTo('#pedidos');
```

As you are use **jQuery 1.4**, use **.live**

```
$(".dispatch_pedido").live('click', function() {
    alert("hello world");        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The element you are adding the click event to doesn't exist when the document is ready.

Try:

```
$('<tr id="data[i].id" class="pedido_row">').html("
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].user_created + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].store_created + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].product_code + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].product_info + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].warehouse + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].cost_center + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].quantity + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">" + data[i].time_created + "</td>
<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\"><input class=\"dispatch_pedido\" id=\"0\" type=\"button\" value=\"Despachar Pedido\" /></td>
").appendTo('#pedidos');

$(".dispatch_pedido").click(function(){
    alert('waffles are awesome!')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this right after adding the dynamic html:

```
 $('.dispatch_pedido').unbind('click');
 $(document).on('click', ".dispatch_pedido", function() {
        alert("hello world");        
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if($('.dispatch_pedido').length > 0 )
       {
            $('.dispatch_pedido').click(function()
              {
                 //TO DO
              }
            );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready();`
Thats probably because your DOM is prepared just when your page is ready.